# How to structure output to write to csv within a for statement in R?

Tags: r, csv, output

I'm running a conditional logistic regression analysis on different individuals using a for statement in R. The code for this is pretty straightforward:

```
for(ID in unique(Hour168Fin$BAND)){
modelone = clogit(Hour168Fin$OBSERVED ~ Hour168Fin$LNSTEPLENG + Hour168Fin$PowCross + Shrub +
strata(Hour168Fin$STEPID), data=Hour168Fin, subset = which(ID==Hour168Fin$BAND))
```

I'm interested in very specific parts of the output, so I've structured the output to give me exactly the coefficients I need using this:

```
x1beta = as.numeric(summary(modelone)$coef[1,1])
x2beta = as.numeric(summary(modelone)$coef[2,1])
x3beta = as.numeric(summary(modelone)$coef[3,1])
x1SE = as.numeric(summary(modelone)$coef[1,3])
x2SE = as.numeric(summary(modelone)$coef[2,3])
x3SE = as.numeric(summary(modelone)$coef[3,3])
x1pvalue = as.numeric(summary(modelone)$coef[1,5])
x2pvalue = as.numeric(summary(modelone)$coef[2,5])
x3pvalue = as.numeric(summary(modelone)$coef[3,5])
modelAIC = AIC(modelone)

results = table(x1beta, x1SE, x1pvalue, x2beta, x2SE, x2pvalue, x2beta, x2SE, x2pvalue, modelAIC, rownames = ID)}
```

In R, I can see all the results in the format I'm looking for, but when I use this to get these results into a csv:

```
write.csv = (results, file = "TrialOut.csv")
```

I'm only getting the results of 1 unique ID. I've tried embedding the write.csv statement in the for statement, and using it outside of it with the same results. Any suggestions? I'm really baffled because I can see the results in R but can't seem to get that to translate to a csv.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The value of `ID` is just the last time thru the for loop. Also the `results` gets overwritten every time.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for a way to get all of the IDs into the csv file. Any way to stop the results from being overwritten?

Comment: It should work if you `write.csv` inside the for loop... are you by chance overwriting your file? If inside the for loop your filename should be have an index e.g. `file=paste0("TrialOut_", ID, ".csv")`.

Comment: If you changed it to a data frame you could use `results <- rbind(results, .....)`. Set `results` as an empty data frame before the loop, and the write after. Not sure if it would work on a table

Comment: The paste option created a separate file for each ID.  I'm looking to get all the results into one single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including the `write.csv` call inside the loop, and use `append = TRUE`:

```
for (...) {

# ...
# ...

write.csv(results, file = "someFile.csv", append = TRUE)

}
```

Comment: Hm. This ran but didn't work.  I still ended up with the very last ID results only, and this error: 17: In write.csv(results, file = "TrialOut.csv", append = TRUE) :
  attempt to set 'append' ignored

Comment: Hmm maybe try with write.table instead of write.csv then

Comment: Ah!  This worked: `write.table(results, file = "TrialOut.csv", append=TRUE, sep = ",", col.names = FALSE)`.  Leaving out col.names=FALSE resulted in having the column names show up in every other line - just FYI for anyone who may have a similar question.  Thank you!